# Geany4Windows text editing

Tags: geany

I have used Geany4Windows for a long while but am still confused how it handles editing text files and I decided to ask for help now!

If I open a new file from menu I can type plain text in it and yet when I save the file it does not give a .txt extension option to save as and while I can add this to the end of the name I give to the file and save it and it saves as a .txt file with no problem. If instead, I do not do this and leave off the file extension, and then save it, it saves as a file with no extension!

There is an option to open a new template file but in my Geany4Windows there is no .txt template. I tried making my own by making a file with a {fileheader} and saving it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\data\templates\files as file.txt.

This does then give me the option to open a new template text file but when I save that the text fileheader produces this:

```
 /*
 * mynewdefaulttexttemplateGeany.txt.txt
 * 
 * Copyright 2014 Richard <Richard@RPDHPI5PAVILION>
 * 
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
 * MA 02110-1301, USA.
 * 
 * 
 */My first text file from new text template I just created in Geany.....
```

The file header shows as >> mynewdefaulttexttemplateGeany.txt.txt << with a double .txt extension.

If I could fix this file header for my default template file.txt file (so it doesn't save with the extension added twice), I would be happier working with plain text files in Geany4Windows! Anyone know how I can fix this please? Thanks.

***MY EDIT***
I have fixed this now and it was helped by Matthews post below (& see my comment on that).
To recap the solution: 
I made a new custom file type file.txt with {fileheader}
To make this work I added the line txt=*.txt to filetype_extensions.conf
Also I created filetypes.txt.conf and added..

> [settings]
> extension=txt
>
> lexer_filetype=C
> [styling=C]
>
> # multiline comments
> comment_open=/*
> comment_close=*/

This works now! See screenshots before & after:
[image: Geany editor with custom .txt file and fileheader extension issue & not in red text as default]

after:
[image: Geany editor with custom .txt file and fileheader now working correctly as default]

I do like Geany4Windows but it can be interesting trying to customise it to use new filetypes etc etc. Happy coding & editing with Geany on Windows & Linux (does it run on Mac?!). I'm pleased this is fixed now.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a file named like `filetypes.Text.conf` and inside of it put:

```
[settings]
extension=txt
```

Then add it to `filetype_extensions.conf` `[Extensions]` section like:

```
...
Text=*.txt;*.text; etc...
...
```

The manual has more details about custom filetypes.

Comment: Hi Matthew..you super star!Thank you..I have been struggling most of the night with the Geany manual and was very close to solving it myself when I checked back here and found your answer that has confirmed how I can fix this! All is done now & I can easily open a new text(.txt) file with the custom file.txt template and when I save it the file name in the header is exactly right (no duplicate extension). My only issue is that the file header colour is no longer in the default red for all my other custom Geany files (it is black text)..there must be some colour code to add to the .conf file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't check in on S.O. enough :)  I'm not sure I understand, but you won't get any syntax highlighting with a plain text filetype since there's no real syntax to highlight. It shouldn't affect any of your other filetypes though, unless you have their filetype set as something else (ex. as plain text instead of whatever programming language).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *.txt-file by saving your file like `foo.txt` or `baa.txt`. Plain text not necessarily having `txt`-extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I can do that as I state in my question, but I want a default .txt file template such that I can save withoiut having to add the file extension when saving. Most other editors I have used eg PSPad & others give an option to create a new text file .txt extension but Geany does not appear to do so. I can add my own custom .txt template but I need to use the fileheader so it does not add x2 .txt extensions!

Answer (score 0):

To explain Matthews answer more, you have been using filetype None, which does not have an extension. By creating the filetype Geany now knows about files with extension .txt

BTW you can edit filetype_extensions.conf by menu->tools->configuration files-> filetype_extensions.conf.